# Restrict the refresh option from IE context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am using the IE context menu in my WPF application in Web Browser control. When I press the F5 or refresh option in context menu the content in the web Browser control gets disappear.  I already restrict the action of F5 but not able to restrict the action of refresh option in context menu. Is there any way to disable or remove the refresh option from IE context menu or can able to change the function of refresh option in context menu.

Comment: Why does the loaded content disappear after refreshing? it should be reloaded, not disappear.

Comment: Hi Kennyzx,For my application the content is disappear.web browser content is used as a user control.